Dynamic variable in Gitlab's CI/CD
I have gitlab runners for my laravel project. I want to deploy in a directory, name of it will consist of date and time joined with "_" for what i want run
echo `date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M"`.

What i should put in the variable value?
I now have:
variables:
  SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
  CURRENT_ID: echo `date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M"`

But it just outputs this text.

It depends on what you want to use this variable for.

If this variable is only used in this job, then you can define it in the before_script or in the script before using it:

job_name:
  stage: stage_name
  before_script:
    - |
      # Export and use a variable
      export CURRENT_ID="$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")"
      echo "${CURRENT_ID}"


If this variable must be dynamic but you agree to pass it on to the next job according with the documentation:

job_A:
  stage: stage_A
  script:
    - echo "CURRENT_ID=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

job_B:
  stage: stage_B
  script:
    - echo "${CURRENT_ID}" # output of 'date' command


If none of the above solutions really work then you can generate child pipelines defined by yamls generated during the pipeline by following this documentation: Trigger a dynamic child pipeline

